# Передача стоимости позиции при создании заказа покупателя

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Ситуация следующая: создается заказ покупателя на стороне МС через имеющийся API.
По каким причинам цена позиции в заказе покупателя в 100 раз меньше передаваемой со стороны интернет-магазина?
Почему я должен умножать ее на 100, чтобы на стороне МоегоСклада отобразилось корректное значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой Склад хранит стоимость целым числом в копейках. Отсюда и х100 к цене в рублях.